# How can I get a sublist from a Record in Netsuite using Suitescript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a scheduled suite script where it gets a sublist and applies some conditions to evaluate the result and send automated mail. But I couldn't get the sublist ID and can't retrieve the sublist data. Can I know where to get the sublist ID and how to create a way to retrieve the sublist data?

```
var sublistlines = currentRecord.getLineCount({
                    sublistId: 'SublistID',
                });
for (var i = 0; i < sublistlines; i++) {
                    var item = currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'SublistID',
                    fieldId: 'SublistFieldId',
                    line: i
                    });
                    if(condition){
                       action()
                    }
```

Sublistlines returns -1

Comment: Sometime it doesn't show the sublist values, if you could explain on which record you are working and which sublist you are looking for . That will be better to provide any help.

Comment: And In scheduled script, you need to load the particular record  and use that variable to get any details of that record. I hope you are loading the record first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getSublists()` method to get all sublists deployed to a record. Here is an example script that I wrote that if called should give you all the values associated to all sublists related to an invoice record.

```
// get an array of all sublistId's available to the invoice record.
// you can use this with any record type and can perform this in client script or the debugger to find the sublist you're looking for.
var rec = record.load({type: record.Type.INVOICE, id: invoiceId});
var sublistIdArr = rec.getSublists();

// if you want to, you get more information about each sublist
for (var i = 0; i < sublistIdArr.length; i++) {
  var sublistId = sublistIdArr[i];
  var sublistFields = rec.getSublistFields({sublistId: sublistId});
  var sublistLineCount = rec.getLineCount({sublistId: sublistId});
  for (var line = 0; line < sublistLineCount; line++) {
    var sublistObject = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < sublistFields.length; j++) {
      var fieldId = sublistFields[j];
      sublistObject[fieldId] = rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: sublistId, fieldId: fieldId, line: line});
    }
    // do whatever you want with that sublist object here to see what is information is available.

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the record's details of its sublist ids and field ids using schema browser here is the URL and find the record with starting letter, in lower case there will be internal ids of each fields or sublist. Schema browser URL-

https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/salesorder.html

And you can also download field explorer chrome extension for netsuite through google and use it to view field ids on records.

Field Explorer chrome extension-
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-field-explorer/cekalaapeajnlhphgdpmngmollojdfnd?hl=en